# MongoDB + Hapi JS + Role Based Access Control (RBAC)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, hapi.js, rbac, hapi

Am currently learning  HapiJs development, developing an Interview Process (i.e. HRM), and **want to implement Role Based Access Control (RBAC)** for that. How do I set up roles & permission on MongoDB?

I want 3 roles  :

- ADMIN
- MANAGER
- USER

**ADMIN**- similar to Manager, can do anything in the application. C, R, U, D permissions for the Interview Process and other users too. Can Create an Interview Process & assign them to any MANAGER or USER directly. Update or Delete either an Interview Process or a User at any time.

**MANAGER** - similar to Admin, has the power to do anything on his Data - C,R,U,D for the Interview Process. Can create any USER. Can only Read & add comments for Interview Processes created by ADMIN &  assigned to him/her.

**USER** - Can only Read and add comments to the Interview Process assigned to him/her.

To sum it up :

```
ADMIN - C, R, U, D [Global Level]
MANAGER - C, R, U, D [Private] + R, U [Assigned to him]
USER - R, U [Assigned to him]
```

I understand that I need to have USERS & ROLES collections. Where ROLES in turn should have PERMISSIONS etc. How do I wire them all?